# Swift: Change the UIImageView image in multiple viewControllers at the same time

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimageview, viewcontroller

I am trying to change the image of multiple UIImageView outlets across 3 different view controllers at the same time. I thought I might be able to do it by making the @IBOutlets for each UIImageView "global" but it won't let me do that. I then thought that I could change it through a prepareForSegue, but that only lets me change one.

Is there anyway I can change the image of these 3 UIImageViews at the same time?

Comment: Do they all exist at the same time? Explain your architecture.

Comment: To put Wain's comment a different way: you don't _have_ 3 different view controllers at the same time, do you? So the whole notion makes no sense.

Comment: Where is the image coming from? Is this for a background image like changing wall paper kind of thing? You could use NSUserDefaults and save the selected image then in the other VC read the NSUserDefaults and set the image.

Comment: I think they can be in the stack like subviews. So I didn't make three at the same time but two I did.